# Java boolean initialisation

Tags: java, static, boolean

Why this code runs normal

```
static boolean bool;

    public static void main() {
        System.out.println(bool);
    }
```

While here

```
public static void main() {
        boolean bool;
        System.out.println(bool);
    }
```

I have error: Variable 'bool' might not have been initialized

Aren't both of them have default value `false`?

Comment: See also [Definite Assignment in the JLS, Ch. 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html): "Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs."

Comment: *Aren't both of them have default value false?* -- No.  Class and instance variables are implicitly initialized, local variables are not.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how Java works. All "static" and "instance" class members of primitive types are initialized by the compiler. In particular, `boolean` are always initialize to `false` (that is your first piece of code).
Instead, local variable (second piece of code) "must" be manually initialized, otherwise you get a compilation error.